# What mean "||" in initialization of variable

Tags: javascript

On w3school i read about js window and encounter such piece of code.

```
var h = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight;
```

What does this mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators

Comment: Mandatory read: [Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means if `window.innerHeight` is falsy (e.g. `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `''`, `NaN`, `false`), then use `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, and if that is falsy, then use `document.body.clientHeight`.

Comment: falsy values include null, false, undefined, 0, ""(empty string), NaN

Comment: When I was young lad I would trip myself up with if (!someVar) when someVar was numerical and could be 0... It's good to know what can return falsy!

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer to include the full list of falsies.

Comment: Not the full list, I'm afraid (for example, `false` is also falsy :P)

Comment: Doh!  Thanks @Amadan!